# use of average aggregate function inside if clause

Tags: mysql

i'm writing a query where i need resultant from select stmt based on conditions on avg() aggregate function,

but in mysql it is giving error as **Error Code : 1111 ,
Invalid use of group function**

```
select 
if( avg(FLD_TKTS) > 1 and avg(FLD_TKTS) <= 2  ,  '1-2' , 0) as fld_avg_1_2,
if( avg(FLD_TKTS) > 3 and avg(FLD_TKTS) <= 4  ,  '3-4' , 0) as fld_avg_3_4
from tbl
group by region;
```

Is there is any other method to do this?

Comment: Can you show the table information? The query looks fine with me.

Comment: Query looks OK, must be something with table..

Comment: Not sure of MySQL but in oracle or sql server we use Case statement (as there is no if) some thing like this Select (Case when avg(FLD_TKTS) > 1 then avg(FLD_TKTS) else 0 end) as fld_avg from tbl group by region;

Comment: You syntax looks fine to me also.

Answer (score 2):

Query:

```
select 
CASE WHEN avg(FLD_TKTS) > 1 and avg(FLD_TKTS) <= 2 THEN '1-2'
     ELSE '0' END as fld_avg_1_2,
CASE WHEN avg(FLD_TKTS) > 3 and avg(FLD_TKTS) <= 4 THEN '3-4' 
     ELSE '0' END as fld_avg_3_4
from tbl
group by region
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
  region,
  if(fld_avg > 1 and fld_avg <= 2, '1-2', 0) as fld_avg_1_2,
  if(fld_avg > 3 and fld_avg <= 4, '3-4', 0) as fld_avg_3_4
from
(
  select 
    region,
    avg(FLD_TKTS) fld_avg
  from 
    tbl
  group by 
    region
) a;
```

Comment: Subquery is not a correlated subquery so should be pretty efficient.

Comment: @Kickstart Even a correlated subquery can be very fast as long as the right indexes are defined.

Comment: Very true if dealing with a small number of rows. Otherwise you land up with a fast sub query being performed many times which rapidly adds up. This is not a correlated sub query so avoid this issue completely and should be fast. Not sure why @sourcecode thinks it is not a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think a subquery would be a good solution:

```
SELECT 
    IF( avg_fld_tkts > 1 and avg_fld_tkts <= 2  ,  '1-2' , 0) as fld_avg_1_2,
    IF( avg_fld_tkts > 3 and avg_fld_tkts <= 4  ,  '3-4' , 0) as fld_avg_3_4
(
    SELECT avg(FLD_TKTS) AS avg_fld_tkts
    from tbl
    group by region
) t1
```